# Find 2D plane in the center of 3D object

Tags: algorithm, matrix, 3d, 2d, plane

I'm building a segmentation algorithm. I'm segmenting pieces of paper in a book that have been slightly crumpled. Imagine taking a piece of paper, crumpling it into a ball, and then trying to straighten it back out.

The piece of paper is an actually 3D object (has depth -- small but still existent), but I want to segment a 2D plane running through the geometric center of the 3D object. Is this a center of mass problem?

I have a 3D matrix of binary values -- 1 being on the piece of paper, and 0 not on the piece of paper.

What kind of algorithm can I run to find the 2D plane?

Comment: depends on what you mean by the "center". Do you mean CofM or geometrical center?

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah geometrical center

Comment: so just average all of the mesh points; by the binary matrix do you mean you've voxelized the paper? is it still crumpled or "straightened"

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah yes, voxels. It is still crumpled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want a 3D *least-squares plane fit*. This will minimize the separation between your plane and the voxel points. See here for math and code: http://www.ilikebigbits.com/blog/2015/3/2/plane-from-points

Comment: @KendallWeihe no prob. there was also a StackOverflow post on this, but it had a lot of rather opaque matrix math. At least this site has some code